# Create a bug automatically when test fails by Azure Devops Rest api calls

Tags: azure, jenkins, azure-devops, postman

Currently my project use a postman and export a collection to run via Jenkins pipeline. So is there anyway to integrate when testcases is fails in jenkins then calls Azure devops rest api to create a bug.

Please help. Much appreciated it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the terminology translates to Azure Devops but we do it a lot with Jira, where the Jenkins pipeline creates a Jira issue by calling the Jira endpoint using the [HTTP request](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/) plugin. I see that Azure DevOps also has a [similar endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) used to create work items, so you should be able to call that endpoint with a `POST` request to create the bug. This is how you would create a post using `httprequest`:

```
httpRequest([
      acceptType        : 'APPLICATION_JSON',
      authentication    : '<credentials>',
      contentType       : 'APPLICATION_JSON',
      httpMode          : 'POST',
      requestBody       : '''{
           "content": {"key": "value"}
      }''',
      responseHandle    : 'NONE',
      url               : "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/${type}?api-version=6.0",
      validResponseCodes: '200,201',
]);
```

You could also simply use `curl` to make the `POST` request. You could also search around for any plugins that handle this for you, which would be an approach preferrable to the above methods.

You mention you have already tried this with Postman, so what is preventing you from implementing this into Jenkins?

Comment: So my project is api's and I write all the testcases in postman and export a collection to run in jenkins everyday